# Gradient colors in Flutter

Tags: flutter

How to get gradients like in this picture in flutter?

[image: how to get gradients like this in flutter?]

Answer (score 0):

```
container(
  decoration:BoxDecoration(
    gradient: LinearGradient(
    begin: Alignment.topRight,
    end: Alignment.bottomLeft
         colors: [
               //Add your desired colors
              ],
  )
)
```

Take a look at https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/painting/LinearGradient-class.html for further references

Comment: Not giving the same result as the picture above

Comment: It is just an example of how to implement gradient. You can use colors on that image to get the result

Comment: implementing the gradient is not a problem. aligning the 4 colours each in every corner is the tricky part.